# LaTeX  template gallery

Tags: templates, repositories

I know that there's CTAN but I would like to know if any **LaTeX template gallery** (commercial or not) exists on the web. I mean something where I have some PDF examples that I could preview, and a downloadable zip archive with the .tex source file and all the other resources needed (packages, sty, images...).

The best would be something like the website templates industry does (Themeforest).

I'm a non expert but happy LaTeX user. I use TextMate for editing .tex documents and the MacTeX distribution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might be interested in the TeX Showcase http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/.

Answer (score 17):

This site has some nice templates:

http://www.latextemplates.com/

Comment: Since April 2012, you have got 14 cups of coffee.

Answer (score 10):

A more specialised examples gallery, dedicated to drawing pictures with pgf/TikZ, can be found on [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/).

Some general templates/examples are available on [howtoTeX.com](http://www.howtotex.com/category/templates/).

Comment: linkrot: howtoTeX.com

Answer (score 9):

I've created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/) with many examples. Most of them are not compiled, but every example is in one separate folder and has its own Makefile. So you can simply run `make` to get the pdf.
Or (for TikZ examples) you can also run `make png` to create a png, `make svg` and `make gif`.

Comment: This is very useful! THX @moose

Answer (score 6):

I probably arrived late to the party, but I'm surprised because Overleaf has not been mentioned.

In its gallery you can browse all the available templates and, moreover, edit them using Overleaf (free online service): https://www.overleaf.com/gallery

The thing I prefer about the service is the partial compilation of files, giving the possibility to see how the code is being compiled at code-time.

Comment: The party never ends...

Comment: I am quite impressed with their book templates. This should have been the top voted one IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to about [PGFPlots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) and [PSTricks](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples).

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is what you had in mind. The arXiv http://arxiv.org/ is a huge depository. You can view the .pdf which is the whole idea and the source code is also available.

Of course this comes with the disclaimer that you have to decide which examples you want to follow. This won't show you what is good practice. If you find something similar to what you are trying to do you can look and see how it was done in that case.

Answer (score 2):

There is one rather recent, but good LaTeX template gallery: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/

It does not contain PDF examples as such as you would like to have (unless you run the .tex file in question). It does, however, contain an overview picture and downloadable .zip archive containing all necessary files to run the .tex file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Jesse The question is not entirely clear (as essentially this is not a question). The site I mentioned provides downloadable .zip files as requested by OP. I edited my answer to give a better answer for "the question".

Answer (score 1):

There is also the XeTeX showcase over at http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactextras/Demos/XeTeX-showcase/00Start-Here.html

Answer (score 0):

Just like Martin Thoma, I've also created a github repository. [Link](https://github.com/adamrees89/LaTeX-Templates)

Comment: I don't like the idea of everybody sharing templates.

Comment: Don't use them then