# Public storage of TeX templates

Tags: templates, database

It exists a public storage of TeX templates?
I mean that people could search a template that is standardized or just nicely formated eg. Dr thesis, official papers, books, articles and so ...

It would be great to have a database of all papers.

i have found this [howtotex](http://www.howtotex.com/templates/) it hase screenshots an description, but just few templates available :(

Comment: Is it a duplicate? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1362/2099

Answer (score 4):

The standard place for all (La)TeX relevant packages, classes and related code is the [Comprehensive TeX Archive Network (CTAN)](http://www.ctan.org/). It contains all available source code as long the authors of it uploaded it to it. The main distributions TeXLive and MikTeX use it as their source of packages. There are some classes suitable for Ph.D. thesis, etc. However, there is not specific "template" category as far as I know.

The issue with templates is that there are so many different possible styles and so you a template is either very general and very specific, which in both cases doesn't make it very useful for a wider range. For example a Ph.D. thesis will look quite different in different countries or even for different colleges in one country. Not to mention between different fields of study.

I put a template for German final year project reports ("Diplomarbeit") which a made for my own Diplomarbeit some years ago:
http://www.scharrer-online.de/wiki/LaTeX/Templates/Diplomarbeit
(I actually have to review it again, my TeX-fu is now much stronger)

Comment: OK, so when it doesn't exist, i must make a webside, where people can upload, share and search TeX templates. It must have a title, screenshots and description. I'll be back! Meanwhile: Hasta la vista babe!