# Templates for NOT math-based books?

Tags: templates, book-design

I need neat templates for books which aren't about maths or any other science - just your everyday HarryPotter-ish book you read to get your mind off all the bad things happening during the day.

So it needs a decent simple front page (not really obligatory, those can be found everywhere), and neat interesting headings.

Comment: Related questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31196/template-for-a-book-for-children http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66902/latex-template-for-writing-a-novel http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1362/latex-template-gallery

Answer (score 3):

The [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) package has a nice selection of built-in styles for chapter headings. It's also got a number of other features a novelist might want. Also, if you use it with LuaTeX then you can use system fonts easily and some advanced typographic features like [microtype](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) and [selnolig](https://github.com/micoloretan/selnolig).  I consider all four of those features required usage for a novel (at least for the one I'm writing).

Comment: Right? I only discovered `selnolig` recently and now I cannot imagine ever living without it.

Comment: @bfootdav - You just made day!!!

Comment: @Mico , not sure how to contact you directly so I guess I'll do it this way. 1st, awesome package -- this kind of attention to detail is what makes TeX so great and perhaps unique among the competition. 2nd, any idea when the package will be out of beta or at least available on CTAN? 3rd, the README mentions a manual but I have been unable to find it.  I figured out the basic usage from the examples but a manual would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: @bfootdav - I've updated the selnolig package's file on GitHub, and have made sure that the user guide is included; look for the file named "selnolig.pdf". The UG's header page provides my email address in case you want to send me comments (which would be very welcome).

Comment: @bfootdav - I've uploaded the `selnolig` package to the CTAN; it now resides at http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/luatex/latex/selnolig. (The selnolig site GitHub will remain active and updated as well.)